# Elasticsearch repository not allowing default field type

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

While creating an index Elasticsearch Repository does not allow default type. If field type annotation is missing, assuming default type, the Spring data elasticsearch mapper throws exception and then creates some default mapping when I save the first object.
I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to not annotate every field in of my data objects?
I'm using Spring Data Elasticsearch v3.1.8 and Elasticsearch 6.2.2.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the code for your `@Document` annotated entity and the exception you get from the Mapper?

Answer (score 0):

There is effectively a way to avoid annoting every fields. Elasticsearch need to create the mapping of the document.

You can indicate to spring how the document need to be mapped with `@Field` or by providing the mapping configuration.

With spring just annotate the document with `@Mapping` to set mapping file location.

Also you could just create the mapping using Elasticsearch PUT mapping API.

```
@Document(indexName = Produit.INDEX, type = ProduitES.TYPE, shards = 1)
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/mappings-produit.json")
public class Produit {

 private String code;
 private String name;

 ...
}
```

The mapping file in `resources/mappings/mappings-produit.json` folder :

```
{
  "produit": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "code": {
        "type": "text",
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't annotate a field with the `@Field` annotation, Spring Data Elasticsearch will not put the field in the mapping, so it will be automatically mapped by ES when a document is inserted.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!
I think I just won't annotate fields with default mapping.